# Controlling a Google TV remotely via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-tv

I have a Sony Google TV running firmware 3.2. Is it possible to install a simple SSH server and log into it remotely via SSH, and then issue commands to change TV channels, load websites in Chrome, etc? I've seen some [similar questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-there-some-ssh-server-for-android) on this topic, but nothing specific to Google TV devices. I tried installing SSHDroid and QuickSSHd, but the Market said that neither were "compatible with my device".

Answer (score 2):

Apps must be coded specifically to allow for installation on Google TV devices.  In 3.2 update, Google even disabled side-loading of apps, so the old trick from 2.x days to install APKs via a dropbox account won't work.

Modders from [GTVhacker](http://www.gtvhacker.com/) site managed to find an exploit in Sony units that allows for [installing a custom kernel](http://www.gtvhacker.com/index.php/Running_Unsigned_Kernels_On_Sony_GTV) and a rooted build of 3.2.  With that build it's possible to [enable side-loading](http://www.gtvhacker.com/index.php/Enable_Non-Market_Apps_on_Sony_GTV) of apps, and then you can install them via ADB:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.XXX:5555
adb install C:\path\to\apk\AppName.apk
```

Where "XXX" is the IP address of your GTV box/TV.

Keep in mind that the usual warnings of rooting apply, such as voiding the warranty, etc.